# Autofac time driven [tagged] scope

Tags: autofac

I'm after  sort of singleton scope which auto-disposes itself in configured time interval.
Tried to employ pooled instances, but it lacks the API to evict the cache.
Does such scope exist ? What is the proper way to implement it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Autofac does not have any out-of-the-box concept of disposing a scope based on a time interval. This is something you'd have to create and manage in your application code. there is no "proper way" to implement it necessarily because it will be based on your application needs.

Comment: Thanks @travis, Would it be reasonable to ask you to  extend pool strategy  API (interfaces) to expose method that controls whether or not the object should be returned to pool rather than just notifying it's being returned ?

Comment: And may be more fine-tuned API for cache eviction, marking pooled objects as expired ect ..... 
For example, I can think about pooled objects that are alive within configured timeout (like DB connection) and  they should be validated before returning from the pool, (like `select 1 from dual`) to check the connection is still valid, if not valid - remove from pool and try next one

Comment: If there's something you want, file an issue and explain it; then consider also filing a pull request to implement it. As easy as asking for something on SO might be, there's already a process in place for it.